# WPF + EF. context.SaveChanges() doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, frameworks, entity

I'm a new WPF developer and I'm writing a WPF project for a hostel. I use Entity Framework with a DB first approach. In the UI I have a datagrid which is binded to collection of students. And there are `"RowEditEnding"` and `"AddingNewItem"` events are declared.

So what I want is just to be able to edit and add new students. Everythings works fine, without errors but `SaveChanges()` method doesn't save entities to the database.

My code of `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    HostelDBEntities db = new HostelDBEntities();

    private bool isInsertMode = false;
    private bool isBeingEdited = false;

    private ObservableCollection<Student> GetStudentsList()
    {
        var list = from e in db.Students select e;
        return new ObservableCollection<Student>(list);
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        studentsGrid.ItemsSource = GetStudentsList();
    }

    private void studentsGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        Student student = new Student();
        Student st = e.Row.DataContext as Student;
        if (isInsertMode)
        {
            var InsertRecord = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to add a new student?", "Question", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
            if (InsertRecord == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                student.FirstName = st.FirstName;
                student.LastName = st.LastName;
                student.Patronymic = st.Patronymic;
                db.Students.Add(student);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else studentsGrid.ItemsSource = GetStudentsList();
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void studentsGrid_AddingNewItem(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        isInsertMode = true;
    }
}
```

And my `XAML` code of `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="studentsGrid" Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            RowEditEnding="studentsGrid_RowEditEnding"   AddingNewItem="studentsGrid_AddingNewItem" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding StudentId, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="StudentId" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="First Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Patronymic, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Patronymic" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Last Name" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Can anyone help me to understand how to solve it? To make the context to save changes to the database.

Thank you.

Comment: I know you say you get no errors, but wrap the `SaveChanges()` in a `try..catch` block and see what is occurring.

Comment: @Ric Made it, everything goes well anyway, without errors

Comment: does it work when you are adding entities but not updating?

Comment: @Ric No, it doesn't work in both cases

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change your XAML so that

> isInsertMode = true;

get's called when your **RowEditEnding**-event fires. You actually call it on

> AddingNewItem="studentsGrid_AddingNewItem"

which leads to firing, when your model doesn't hold any data at this point even before you are able to type any character. You cannot save ***"nothing"*** to your db. You can also check this by putting a breakpoint before ***isInsertMode = true;***.
Calling it in

> studentsGrid_RowEditEnding()

ensures that db.SaveChanges get's called when the row looses its focus.